# how to redirect "example.com" to "localhost/example.com"

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, localhost, mamp

I am using MAMP to develop a Wordpress site locally. I've managed to map the domain  "example.com" to localhost (127.0.0.1) in my hosts file like so:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

Consequently, "example.com" redirects to my document root:

```
example.com --> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

This is fine if I'm working on a single site; all my projects files go in 'htdocs'. The problem is I am working on multiple sites simultaneously, therefore I need more specific redirects, like so:

```
example1.com --> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example1.com
example2.com --> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example2.com
example3.com --> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example3.com
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, Apache can do this. It's called "name based virtual hosting". Map all the names to `127.0.0.1` and in the Apache config, map the names to the directories.

Comment: thank you. Thanks to your lead I got it working.

Comment: for future reference, MAMP Pro has a feature that sets up virtual hosts automatically without having to touch any code. You just have to click on the "Hosts" tab and the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a minor change:
You can create directories under your root path for every domain:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example1
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example2
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example3
```

Then you can add a rule in your `.htaccess` file for 301 redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example1.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example2.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example2 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example3.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example3 [L]
```

If all 3 domains point to the same server - it'll work (I've done it with two domains in the past).